# Webpage not available in Cordova Android app

Tags: java, android, cordova, wildfly, keycloak

**EDIT: I have been progressing through this problem and retracing all of my steps. I am happy to reduce the size of this question and get more to the exact details if it is confusing. Currently I am at the point where it seems like Keycloak only intends to redirect me to https://, which should be a Wildfly server configuration issue, as far as I can tell.**

**EDIT: I reduced my question, but this introduced confusion, so I rollbacked the question to what it was originally, the most relevant parts are at the bottom though, where I will note this**

I am tearing my hair out trying to figure out what might be causing this problem.

I've got the following error message on a simulator in Android studio:

[image: Webpage not available]

I am using the identity management system Keycloak - I'll get back to that in a bit.

I have tried changing my CSP to be very permissive:

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' * data:"
  />
```

I have installed inappbrowser, I have set my intents and allow-navigations pretty liberally in my config.xml:

```
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<allow-intent href="gap://*" />
<allow-intent href="APPNAMEHERE://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="fb://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="http://stage.APPNAMEHERE.com://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://stage.APPNAMEHERE.com://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://localhost/*"/>
<allow-navigation href="http://localhost/*"/>
<preference name="Hostname" value="localhost" />
<preference name="Scheme" value="https" />
<preference name="MixedContentMode" value="0" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-navigation href="localhost://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="APPNAME://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="fb://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
```

Basically I have tried to make this app as permissive as possible, and still no luck authenticating.

But there's something weirder.

I have another, completely unrelated app, but which also uses this same identity management system. I decided, on a lark, because I was desperate to try connecting against that service here, and it works flawlessly - no issues.

I tried exporting the client from the other Keycloak (a bunch of configuration settings) and using them with minor changes, and no dice. Still the same error.

I am just about tearing my hair out at this point, I've been continuously trying different things and clicking "login" for hours with the exact same result.

What could possibly be preventing me from logging in?

Note, there's an iOS app that works perfectly on this same setup, so it's not the setup.

I'm connecting via OIDC, if that helps anyone.

I'm sorry I can't provide more information, I wish I could find something, anything to grasp at, but I'm completely lost here, it just seems to not be able to find localhost, no matter what I try.

Android console (there is nothing special I am seeing in the Chrome inspector):

```
2019-08-31 10:56:42.002 12062-12191/com.companyname.appname D/InAppBrowser: target = _blank
2019-08-31 10:56:42.003 12062-12062/com.companyname.appname D/InAppBrowser: in blank
2019-08-31 10:56:42.054 12062-12164/com.companyname.appname E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ef
2019-08-31 10:56:42.054 12062-12164/com.companyname.appname E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ef
2019-08-31 10:56:42.168 12062-12170/com.companyname.appname D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xf0677ba0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xd6778770)
2019-08-31 10:56:42.325 12062-12170/com.companyname.appname D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xf0677ba0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xd6778770)
2019-08-31 10:56:42.501 12062-12170/com.companyname.appname D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xf0677ba0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xd6778770)
```

Note, I have replaced the company name of the company this is for with "companyname" and the app name with "appname"

EDIT:

I am also noticing this error when trying a very basic keycloak implementation (the toy example here: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/examples/cordova/www/index.html) on my front end:

```
keycloak.js:1000 Uncaught (in promise) undefined
setError    @   keycloak.js:1000
(anonymous) @   keycloak.js:1261
Channel.fire    @   cordova.js:840
_eventHandler   @   inappbrowser.js:53
cb  @   inappbrowser.js:118
callbackFromNative  @   cordova.js:290
(anonymous) @   VM68:1
```

The code in question, in keycloak.js, pertains to creating a native promise:

```
function createNativePromise() {
    // Need to create a native Promise which also preserves the
    // interface of the custom promise type previously used by the API
    var p = {
        setSuccess: function(result) {
            p.success = true;
            p.resolve(result);
        },

        setError: function(result) {
            p.success = false;
            p.reject(result);
        }
    };
```

Could it possibly be related to inappbrowser?

**ACTUAL RELEVANT PART OF THE QUESTION**

EDIT 2: Digging deeper down...

The error is getting thrown here.

So my guess is that it's due to my redirect url somehow being https://localhost rather than http://localhost, as this is what my redirect URI is.

```
                ref.addEventListener('loaderror', function(event) {
                    if (!completed) {
                        if (event.url.indexOf('http://localhost') == 0) {
                            var callback = parseCallback(event.url);
                            processCallback(callback, promise);
                            closeBrowser();
                            completed = true;
                        } else {
                            promise.setError();
                            closeBrowser();
                        }
                    }
                });

https://localhost/#state=3bc5b8e8-ee17-4c78-861c-6fa62f5e353b&session_state=43d5518d-c278-4245-b181-899783fd2c6b&code=8e50a9c0-d1a6-4ecd-8e91-e85d92350900.43d5518d-c278-4245-b181-899783fd2c6b.863570ca-9c62-41a5-97bb-33880fe6c62d
```

Even when trying:

```
keycloak.init({ onLoad: "check-sso", redirectUri: "http://localhost" })
```

I am still getting the redirect uri of https:// above, which I am strongly thinking is responsible for my error.

My **strong** guess at this point is that this may be related to a Keycloak (which uses Wildfly) configuration setting.

Here is my server setup in Wildfly:

```
        <server name="default-server">
            <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="http" proxy-address-forwarding="true" enable-http2="true"/>
            <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="true"/>
            <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                <http-invoker security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
            </host>
        </server>
```

Comment: Provide your console output. that will help to identify the problem.

Comment: @Aarej - I have added the Android console logs

Comment: How did you configure OIDC client in Keycloak (redirect URL, base URL, ...). Which flow are you using?

Comment: The redirect URI is set as it is above - http://localhost - the origin uri is https://stage.domainname.com/auth/etc/etc

Comment: Hi @CecilRodriguez the only thing that your http-listener configuration has wrong is the ‘redirect-socket=“http”’ attribute. It uses to be “https” to enable https redirection. If you use your keycloak in http, remove this attribute... if you want to force your keycloak to use https change “http” by “https” to enable redirection. I don’t believe that it could be the solution but this is a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why do you think that could be due to a wildfly configuration...

Check please and provide more info:

- Trace your request from Cordova to Keycloak
- What redirect_uri parameter is sent/requested?
- You can try enabling audit like this [audit configuration](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/6.0/server_admin/#login-events) to check the "redirect_uri" parameter.

Keycloak receives a request with a valid redirect uri and then if you are a valid user and the redirect uri received matches with your client configuration... your app will be redirected to your requested redirect_uri.

- Check your client and realm configuration ([example realm configuration for cordova apps](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/examples/cordova/example-realm.json))

**Edited 1: about your wildfly standalone.xml**:
As I said before in comments, your http-listener attribute reditect-socket=“http” is a mistake.
If you want to enable redirection to https replace “http” by “https”. Otherwise remove it.

Attribute “proxy-address-forwarding” must to be used only when your keycloak are behind a reverse proxy (use of x-forwarded-* headers).

---

I tested with Keycloak v6.0.1 and it works. It redirect to 'http://localhost'.

Some points to take in mind:

- don't work with platform 'browser' (use 'android')
- adding 'inappbrowser' and 'whitelist' plugins
- try with a new emulator/runtime instance.
- don't tried with an external identity provider

### Tested with Keycloak v6.0.1

Steps that I followed to do a test with sample project:

1. Download Keycloak source from github [source](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak)
2. Install last version of Android Studio and Gradle (add to PATH)
3. Go to directory 'keycloak/examples/cordova'
4. Download 'keycloak.js' from your Keycloak instance (eg. 'https://yourdomain:port/auth/js/keycloak.js') and put in directory 'keycloak/examples/cordova/www'
5. Open your emulator from Android Studio (install your runtime eg. 'Pixel 2 Api 29').
6. Configure your realm 'example' (import new realm from file: 'keycloak/examples/cordova/example-realm.json')
7. Run commands:

> mkdir platforms plugins
>   cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
>   cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
>   cordova platform add android
>   cordova build android
>   cordova run android

PS: If you have some public test instance to check with it or

Comment: I did all that, and deleted it from my question as it's not relevant. I'll undelete it.

Comment: ok! why do you think that could be a problem with your "wildfly" configuration?

Comment: Because, the error is related to my localhost being https:// rather than http:// - as far as I can tell, this isn't set inside Keycloak's admin console, but due to the settings in wildfly - in standalone.xml

Comment: I believe you need to give me permission to type in the chat, it isn't letting me write anything

Comment: please enable the ability to write a message in the chat, I currently cannot write anything to you

Comment: Nobody figured this out and you were attempting to be the most helpful, so if nobody has the answer in the next 10 hours or so, I'll award you the points

Comment: Hi @CecilRodriguez, how are you? I tried to reproduce your error with cordova and I get same error using platform "browser". Are you trying this with "browser" or with your device connected?

Comment: This is in the Android simulator

Comment: So the big issue here is that localhost is on https://, not http://, which is what it should be. My guess is that it may just be an nginx redirect rule

Comment: Hi @CecilRodriguez, I tried the Android Emulator, and it works. I will update my answer with a few points to check and my configuration. If you give a sample/reproducer project in github, I can test with it.

Answer (score 0):

You'd likely need [cordova-plugin-http2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-http2) or [Cordova Advanced HTTP 2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-advanced-http-2), because of `enable-http2="true"`, the server wants to negotiate `HTTP2`. Setting `enable-http2="false"` would possibly circumvent the problem.

Comment: Hrm, am I losing anything important with not using http2? I'm not really sure the difference between the two protocols. I'm also going to read up on it.

Comment: @CecilRodriguez a `HTTP2` server needs a `HTTP2` client ... and it might be the reason for these `https://` forwards. Another possible reason for `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` might be a self-signed SSL certificate and/or lacking the `network_security_config.xml` on later Android API. `https://localhost` is non-sense, because SSL needs an `A` entry in DNS.

Comment: Hrm, I tried setting http2 to false for both http:// as well as https:// and it still sends to https://localhost

Comment: I'll try to add http2 plugin to cordova and see if that makes a change

Comment: better disable it, because it seems that not even `HTTPS` is working. Can you access that server from a web-browser? I mean, you are requesting `localhost` on an Android device, but likely not running the web-server on that device (`localhost` resolves to `127.0.0.1`, which is the same host which requests).

Comment: disable what exactly?

Comment: When I try to disable http2 on both, I get a new error message about connection refused at https://stage.domainname.com/auth/realms/master/etc/etc/etc that I was not getting before (it fails earlier in the process)

Comment: this might require `<allow-navigation href="https://stage.domainname.com/*"/>`. not sure if `cordova` also white-lists this host-name. it seems at least more likely than `localhost`, assuming that `stage.domainname.com` features an API.

Comment: I'll add it and check

Comment: Though I have allow navigation <allow-navigation href="*" /> as a test, so I would think that would cover it

Comment: see [Network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config)... this also applies to `cordova` on Android platform. `<preference name="Hostname" value="localhost" />` probably should be `<preference name="Hostname" value="stage.domainname.com" />`. does [stage.domainname.com](https://stage.domainname.com/auth/realms/master/etc/etc/etc) work in a browser?