# Keycloak redirect URI gives https://localhost instead of http://localhost

Tags: java, cordova, jboss, wildfly, keycloak

I am trying to authenticate a Cordova Android app on Keycloak.

I made a previous question about it, but I'm paring it down here to just the essentials, as I've discovered a lot over the past 2-3 days.

[Webpage not available in Cordova Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57734603/webpage-not-available-in-cordova-android-app)

Despite the fact that it should theoretically pass back http://localhost/x/y/z I am instead getting https://localhost/x/y/z

This is causing authentication to fail.

Inside keycloak.js:

```
ref.addEventListener('loaderror', function(event) {
                    if (!completed) {
                        if (event.url.indexOf('http://localhost') == 0) {
                            var callback = parseCallback(event.url);
                            processCallback(callback, promise);
                            closeBrowser();
                            completed = true;
                        } else {
                            promise.setError();
                            closeBrowser();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

This error is getting thrown due to the fact that my localhost is going to https://, not http://

This is a sample return:

```
https://localhost/#state=3bc5b8e8-ee17-4c78-861c-6fa62f5e353b&session_state=43d5518d-c278-4245-b181-899783fd2c6b&code=8e50a9c0-d1a6-4ecd-8e91-e85d92350900.43d5518d-c278-4245-b181-899783fd2c6b.863570ca-9c62-41a5-97bb-33880fe6c62d
```

I am trying this:

```
keycloak.init({ onLoad: "check-sso", redirectUri: "http://localhost" })
```

I am strongly guessing it might be due to my standalone.xml settings (I've included the full thing as I don't know what might be causing the issue):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> 

<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:8.0"> 
<extensions> 
<extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/> 
<extension module="org.jboss.as.connector"/> 
<extension module="org.jboss.as.deployment-scanner"/> 
<extension module="org.jboss.as.ee"/> 
<extension module="org.jboss.as.ejb3"/> 
<extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/> 
<extension module="org.jboss.as.jmx"/> 
<extension module="org.jboss.as.jpa"/> 
<extension module="org.jboss.as.logging"/> 
<extension module="org.jboss.as.mail"/> 
<extension module="org.jboss.as.naming"/> 
<extension module="org.jboss.as.remoting"/> 
<extension module="org.jboss.as.security"/> 
<extension module="org.jboss.as.transactions"/> 
<extension module="org.keycloak.keycloak-server-subsystem"/> 
<extension module="org.wildfly.extension.bean-validation"/> 
<extension module="org.wildfly.extension.core-management"/> 
<extension module="org.wildfly.extension.elytron"/> 
<extension module="org.wildfly.extension.io"/> 
<extension module="org.wildfly.extension.request-controller"/> 
<extension module="org.wildfly.extension.security.manager"/> 
<extension module="org.wildfly.extension.undertow"/> 
</extensions> 
<management> 
<security-realms> 
<security-realm name="ManagementRealm"> 
<authentication> 
<local default-user="$local" skip-group-loading="true"/> 
<properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/> 
</authentication> 
<authorization map-groups-to-roles="false"> 
<properties path="mgmt-groups.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/> 
</authorization> 
</security-realm> 
<security-realm name="ApplicationRealm"> 
<server-identities> 
<ssl> 
<keystore path="application.keystore" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="password" alias="server" key-password="password" generate-self-signed-certificate-host="localhost"/> 
</ssl> 
</server-identities> 
<authentication> 
<local default-user="$local" allowed-users="*" skip-group-loading="true"/> 
<properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/> 
</authentication> 
<authorization> 
<properties path="application-roles.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/> 
</authorization> 
</security-realm> 
</security-realms> 
<audit-log> 
<formatters> 
<json-formatter name="json-formatter"/> 
</formatters> 
<handlers> 
<file-handler name="file" formatter="json-formatter" path="audit-log.log" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/> 
</handlers> 
<logger log-boot="true" log-read-only="false" enabled="false"> 
<handlers> 
<handler name="file"/> 
</handlers> 
</logger> 
</audit-log> 
<management-interfaces> 
<http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm"> 
<http-upgrade enabled="true"/> 
<socket-binding http="management-http"/> 
</http-interface> 
</management-interfaces> 
<access-control provider="simple"> 
<role-mapping> 
<role name="SuperUser"> 
<include> 
<user name="$local"/> 
</include> 
</role> 
</role-mapping> 
</access-control> 
</management> 
<profile> 
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:6.0"> 
<console-handler name="CONSOLE"> 
<level name="INFO"/> 
<formatter> 
<named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/> 
</formatter> 
</console-handler> 
<periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true"> 
<formatter> 
<named-formatter name="PATTERN"/> 
</formatter> 
<file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/> 
<suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/> 
<append value="true"/> 
</periodic-rotating-file-handler> 
<logger category="com.arjuna"> 
<level name="WARN"/> 
</logger> 
<logger category="org.jboss.as.config"> 
<level name="DEBUG"/> 
</logger> 
<logger category="sun.rmi"> 
<level name="WARN"/> 
</logger> 
<root-logger> 
<level name="INFO"/> 
<handlers> 
<handler name="CONSOLE"/> 
<handler name="FILE"/> 
</handlers> 
</root-logger> 
<formatter name="PATTERN"> 
<pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/> 
</formatter> 
<formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"> 
<pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/> 
</formatter> 
</subsystem> 
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:bean-validation:1.0"/> 
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:core-management:1.0"/> 
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:5.0"> 
<datasources> 
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS" pool-name="KeycloakDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true"> 
<connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://cactus-stg-postgres.caxdkvuertc9.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/keycloak</connection-url> 
<driver>postgresql</driver> 
<pool> 
<flush-strategy>IdleConnections</flush-strategy> 
</pool> 
<security> 
<user-name>cactusmedia</user-name> 
<password>caCt1Bl0om</password> 
</security> 
<validation> 
<valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLValidConnectionChecker"/> 
<background-validation>true</background-validation> 
<exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLExceptionSorter"/> 
</validation> 
</datasource> 
<drivers> 
<driver name="postgresql" module="org.postgresql.jdbc"> 
<xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource</xa-datasource-class> 
</driver> 
</drivers> 
</datasources> 
</subsystem> 
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:2.0"> 
<deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000" runtime-failure-causes-rollback="${jboss.deployment.scanner.rollback.on.failure:false}"/> 
</subsystem> 
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:4.0"> 
<spec-descriptor-property-replacement>false</spec-descriptor-property-replacement> 
<concurrent> 
<context-services> 
<context-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/context/default" use-transaction-setup-provider="true"/> 
</context-services> 
<managed-thread-factories> 
<managed-thread-factory name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/factory/default" context-service="default"/> 
</managed-thread-factories> 
<managed-executor-services> 
<managed-executor-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default" context-service="default" hung-task-threshold="60000" keepalive-time="5000"/> 
</managed-executor-services> 
<managed-scheduled-executor-services> 
<managed-scheduled-executor-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default" context-service="default" hung-task-threshold="60000" keepalive-time="3000"/> 
</managed-scheduled-executor-services> 
</concurrent> 
<default-bindings context-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/context/default" datasource="java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS" managed-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default" managed-scheduled-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default" managed-thread-factory="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/factory/default"/> 
</subsystem> 
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:5.0"> 
<session-bean> 
<stateless> 
<bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="slsb-strict-max-pool"/> 
</stateless> 
<stateful default-access-timeout="5000" cache-ref="simple" passivation-disabled-cache-ref="simple"/> 
<singleton default-access-timeout="5000"/> 
</session-bean> 
<pools> 
<bean-instance-pools> 
<strict-max-pool name="slsb-strict-max-pool" derive-size="from-worker-pools" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/> 
<strict-max-pool name="mdb-strict-max-pool" derive-size="from-cpu-count" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/> 
</bean-instance-pools> 
</pools> 
<caches> 
<cache name="simple"/> 
<cache name="distributable" passivation-store-ref="infinispan" aliases="passivating clustered"/> 
</caches> 
<passivation-stores> 
<passivation-store name="infinispan" cache-container="ejb" max-size="10000"/> 
</passivation-stores> 
<async thread-pool-name="default"/> 
<timer-service thread-pool-name="default" default-data-store="default-file-store"> 
<data-stores> 
<file-data-store name="default-file-store" path="timer-service-data" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/> 
</data-stores> 
</timer-service> 
<remote connector-ref="http-remoting-connector" thread-pool-name="default"> 
<channel-creation-options> 
<option name="READ_TIMEOUT" value="${prop.remoting-connector.read.timeout:20}" type="xnio"/> 
<option name="MAX_OUTBOUND_MESSAGES" value="1234" type="remoting"/> 
</channel-creation-options> 
</remote> 
<thread-pools> 
<thread-pool name="default"> 
<max-threads count="10"/> 
<keepalive-time time="100" unit="milliseconds"/> 
</thread-pool> 
</thread-pools> 
<default-security-domain value="other"/> 
<default-missing-method-permissions-deny-access value="true"/> 
<log-system-exceptions value="true"/> 
</subsystem> 
<subsystem xmlns="urn:wildfly:elytron:4.0" final-providers="combined-providers" disallowed-providers="OracleUcrypto"> 
<providers> 
<aggregate-providers name="combined-providers"> 
<providers name="elytron"/> 
<providers name="openssl"/> 
</aggregate-providers> 
<provider-loader name="elytron" module="org.wildfly.security.elytron"/> 
<provider-loader name="openssl" module="org.wildfly.openssl"/> 
</providers> 
<audit-logging> 
<file-audit-log name="local-audit" path="audit.log" relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" format="JSON"/> 
</audit-logging> 
<security-domains> 
<security-domain name="ApplicationDomain" default-realm="ApplicationRealm" permission-mapper="default-permission-mapper"> 
<realm name="ApplicationRealm" role-decoder="groups-to-roles"/> 
<realm name="local"/> 
</security-domain> 
<security-domain name="ManagementDomain" default-realm="ManagementRealm" permission-mapper="default-permission-mapper"> 
<realm name="ManagementRealm" role-decoder="groups-to-roles"/> 
<realm name="local" role-mapper="super-user-mapper"/> 
</security-domain> 
</security-domains> 
<security-realms> 
<identity-realm name="local" identity="$local"/> 
<properties-realm name="ApplicationRealm"> 
<users-properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" digest-realm-name="ApplicationRealm"/> 
<groups-properties path="application-roles.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/> 
</properties-realm> 
<properties-realm name="ManagementRealm"> 
<users-properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" digest-realm-name="ManagementRealm"/> 
<groups-properties path="mgmt-groups.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/> 
</properties-realm> 
</security-realms> 
<mappers> 
<simple-permission-mapper name="default-permission-mapper" mapping-mode="first"> 
<permission-mapping match-all="true"> 
<permission-set name="login-permission"/> 
<permission-set name="default-permissions"/> 
</permission-mapping> 
<permission-mapping> 
<principal name="anonymous"/> 
<permission-set name="default-permissions"/> 
</permission-mapping> 
</simple-permission-mapper> 
<constant-realm-mapper name="local" realm-name="local"/> 
<simple-role-decoder name="groups-to-roles" attribute="groups"/> 
<constant-role-mapper name="super-user-mapper"> 
<role name="SuperUser"/> 
</constant-role-mapper> 
</mappers> 
<permission-sets> 
<permission-set name="login-permission"> 
<permission class-name="org.wildfly.security.auth.permission.LoginPermission"/> 
</permission-set> 
<permission-set name="default-permissions"> 
<permission class-name="org.wildfly.extension.batch.jberet.deployment.BatchPermission" module="org.wildfly.extension.batch.jberet" target-name="*"/> 
<permission class-name="org.wildfly.transaction.client.RemoteTransactionPermission" module="org.wildfly.transaction.client"/> 
<permission class-name="org.jboss.ejb.client.RemoteEJBPermission" module="org.jboss.ejb-client"/> 
</permission-set> 
</permission-sets> 
<http> 
<http-authentication-factory name="management-http-authentication" security-domain="ManagementDomain" http-server-mechanism-factory="global"> 
<mechanism-configuration> 
<mechanism mechanism-name="DIGEST"> 
<mechanism-realm realm-name="ManagementRealm"/> 
</mechanism> 
</mechanism-configuration> 
</http-authentication-factory> 
<provider-http-server-mechanism-factory name="global"/> 
</http> 
<sasl> 
<sasl-authentication-factory name="management-sasl-authentication" sasl-server-factory="configured" security-domain="ManagementDomain"> 
<mechanism-configuration> 
<mechanism mechanism-name="JBOSS-LOCAL-USER" realm-mapper="local"/> 
<mechanism mechanism-name="DIGEST-MD5"> 
<mechanism-realm realm-name="ManagementRealm"/> 
</mechanism> 
</mechanism-configuration> 
</sasl-authentication-factory> 
<sasl-authentication-factory name="application-sasl-authentication" sasl-server-factory="configured" security-domain="ApplicationDomain">
<mechanism-configuration> 
<mechanism mechanism-name="JBOSS-LOCAL-USER" realm-mapper="local"/> 
<mechanism mechanism-name="DIGEST-MD5"> 
<mechanism-realm realm-name="ApplicationRealm"/> 
</mechanism> 
</mechanism-configuration> 
</sasl-authentication-factory> 
<configurable-sasl-server-factory name="configured" sasl-server-factory="elytron"> 
<properties> 
<property name="wildfly.sasl.local-user.default-user" value="$local"/> 
</properties> 
</configurable-sasl-server-factory> 
<mechanism-provider-filtering-sasl-server-factory name="elytron" sasl-server-factory="global"> 
<filters> 
<filter provider-name="WildFlyElytron"/> 
</filters> 
</mechanism-provider-filtering-sasl-server-factory> 
<provider-sasl-server-factory name="global"/> 
</sasl> 
</subsystem> 
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:7.0"> 
<cache-container name="keycloak"> 
<local-cache name="realms"> 
<object-memory size="10000"/> 
</local-cache> 
<local-cache name="users"> 
<object-memory size="10000"/> 
</local-cache> 
<local-cache name="sessions"/> 
<local-cache name="offlineSessions"/> 
<local-cache name="loginFailures"/> 
<local-cache name="work"/> 
<local-cache name="authorization"> 
<object-memory size="10000"/> 
</local-cache> 
<local-cache name="keys"> 
<object-memory size="1000"/> 
<expiration max-idle="3600000"/> 
</local-cache> 
<local-cache name="authenticationSessions"/> 
<local-cache name="actionTokens"> 
<object-memory size="-1"/> 
<expiration interval="300000" max-idle="-1"/> 
</local-cache> 
<local-cache name="offlineClientSessions"/> 
<local-cache name="clientSessions"/> 
</cache-container> 
<cache-container name="server" default-cache="default" module="org.wildfly.clustering.server"> 
<local-cache name="default"> 
<transaction mode="BATCH"/> 
</local-cache> 
</cache-container> 
<cache-container name="web" default-cache="passivation" module="org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan"> 
<local-cache name="passivation"> 
<locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/> 
<transaction mode="BATCH"/> 
<file-store passivation="true" purge="false"/> 
</local-cache> 
</cache-container> 
<cache-container name="ejb" aliases="sfsb" default-cache="passivation" module="org.wildfly.clustering.ejb.infinispan"> 
<local-cache name="passivation"> 
<locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/> 
<transaction mode="BATCH"/> 
<file-store passivation="true" purge="false"/> 
</local-cache> 
</cache-container> 
<cache-container name="hibernate" module="org.infinispan.hibernate-cache"> 
<local-cache name="entity"> 
<transaction mode="NON_XA"/> 
<object-memory size="10000"/> 
<expiration max-idle="100000"/> 
</local-cache> 
<local-cache name="local-query"> 
<object-memory size="10000"/> 
<expiration max-idle="100000"/> 
</local-cache> 
<local-cache name="timestamps"/> 
</cache-container> 
</subsystem> 
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:io:3.0"> 
<worker name="default"/> 
<buffer-pool name="default"/> 
</subsystem> 
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxrs:1.0"/> 
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jca:5.0"> 
<archive-validation enabled="true" fail-on-error="true" fail-on-warn="false"/> 
<bean-validation enabled="true"/> 
<default-workmanager> 
<short-running-threads> 
<core-threads count="50"/> 
<queue-length count="50"/> 
<max-threads count="50"/> 
<keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/> 
</short-running-threads> 
<long-running-threads> 
<core-threads count="50"/> 
<queue-length count="50"/> 
<max-threads count="50"/> 
<keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/> 
</long-running-threads> 
</default-workmanager> 
<cached-connection-manager/> 
</subsystem> 
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.3"> 
<expose-resolved-model/> 
<expose-expression-model/> 
<remoting-connector/> 
</subsystem> 
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jpa:1.1"> 
<jpa default-datasource="" default-extended-persistence-inheritance="DEEP"/> 
</subsystem> 
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:keycloak-server:1.1"> 
<web-context>auth</web-context> 
<providers> 
<provider> 
classpath:${jboss.home.dir}/providers/* 
</provider> 
</providers> 
<master-realm-name>master</master-realm-name> 
<scheduled-task-interval>900</scheduled-task-interval> 
<theme> 
<staticMaxAge>2592000</staticMaxAge> 
<cacheThemes>true</cacheThemes> 
<cacheTemplates>true</cacheTemplates> 
<dir>${jboss.home.dir}/themes</dir> 
</theme> 
<spi name="eventsStore"> 
<provider name="jpa" enabled="true"> 
<properties> 
<property name="exclude-events" value="[&quot;REFRESH_TOKEN&quot;]"/> 
</properties> 
</provider> 
</spi> 
<spi name="userCache"> 
<provider name="default" enabled="true"/> 
</spi> 
<spi name="userSessionPersister"> 
<default-provider>jpa</default-provider> 
</spi> 
<spi name="timer"> 
<default-provider>basic</default-provider> 
</spi> 
<spi name="connectionsHttpClient"> 
<provider name="default" enabled="true"/> 
</spi> 
<spi name="connectionsJpa"> 
<provider name="default" enabled="true"> 
<properties> 
<property name="dataSource" value="java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS"/> 
<property name="initializeEmpty" value="true"/> 
<property name="migrationStrategy" value="update"/> 
<property name="migrationExport" value="${jboss.home.dir}/keycloak-database-update.sql"/> 
</properties> 
</provider> 
</spi> 
<spi name="realmCache"> 
<provider name="default" enabled="true"/> 
</spi> 
<spi name="connectionsInfinispan"> 
<default-provider>default</default-provider> 
<provider name="default" enabled="true"> 
<properties> 
<property name="cacheContainer" value="java:jboss/infinispan/container/keycloak"/> 
</properties> 
</provider> 
</spi> 
<spi name="jta-lookup"> 
<default-provider>${keycloak.jta.lookup.provider:jboss}</default-provider> 
<provider name="jboss" enabled="true"/> 
</spi> 
<spi name="publicKeyStorage"> 
<provider name="infinispan" enabled="true"> 
<properties> 
<property name="minTimeBetweenRequests" value="10"/> 
</properties> 
</provider> 
</spi> 
<spi name="x509cert-lookup"> 
<default-provider>${keycloak.x509cert.lookup.provider:default}</default-provider> 
<provider name="default" enabled="true"/> 
</spi> 
<spi name="hostname"> 
<default-provider>request</default-provider> 
<provider name="fixed" enabled="true"> 
<properties> 
<property name="hostname" value="localhost"/> 
<property name="httpPort" value="-1"/> 
<property name="httpsPort" value="-1"/> 
</properties> 
</provider> 
</spi> 
</subsystem> 
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:mail:3.0"> 
<mail-session name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Default"> 
<smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp"/> 
</mail-session> 
</subsystem> 
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:2.0"> 
<remote-naming/> 
</subsystem> 
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:4.0"> 
<http-connector name="http-remoting-connector" connector-ref="default" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/> 
</subsystem> 
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:request-controller:1.0"/> 
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:2.0"> 
<security-domains> 
<security-domain name="other" cache-type="default"> 
<authentication> 
<login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional"> 
<module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/> 
</login-module> 
<login-module code="RealmDirect" flag="required"> 
<module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/> 
</login-module> 
</authentication> 
</security-domain> 
<security-domain name="jboss-web-policy" cache-type="default"> 
<authorization> 
<policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/> 
</authorization> 
</security-domain> 
<security-domain name="jboss-ejb-policy" cache-type="default"> 
<authorization> 
<policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/> 
</authorization> 
</security-domain> 
<security-domain name="jaspitest" cache-type="default"> 
<authentication-jaspi> 
<login-module-stack name="dummy"> 
<login-module code="Dummy" flag="optional"/> 
</login-module-stack> 
<auth-module code="Dummy"/> 
</authentication-jaspi> 
</security-domain> 
</security-domains> 
</subsystem> 
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security-manager:1.0"> 
<deployment-permissions> 
<maximum-set> 
<permission class="java.security.AllPermission"/> 
</maximum-set> 
</deployment-permissions> 
</subsystem> 
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:5.0"> 
<core-environment node-identifier="${jboss.tx.node.id:1}"> 
<process-id> 
<uuid/> 
</process-id> 
</core-environment> 
<recovery-environment socket-binding="txn-recovery-environment" status-socket-binding="txn-status-manager"/> 
<object-store relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/> 
</subsystem> 
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:7.0"> 
<buffer-cache name="default"/> 
<server name="default-server"> 
<http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="http" proxy-address-forwarding="true" enable-http2="true"/> 
<https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="true"/> 
<host name="default-host" alias="localhost"> 
<location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/> 
<http-invoker security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/> 
</host> 
</server> 
<servlet-container name="default"> 
<jsp-config/> 
<websockets/> 
</servlet-container> 
<handlers> 
<file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/> 
</handlers> 
</subsystem> 
</profile> 
<interfaces> 
<interface name="management"> 
<inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/> 
</interface> 
<interface name="public"> 
<inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/> 
</interface> 
</interfaces> 
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}"> 
<socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/> 
<socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/> 
<socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/> 
<socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/> 
<socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/> 
<socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/> 
<socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/> 
<outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp"> 
<remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/> 
</outbound-socket-binding> 
</socket-binding-group> 
</server>
```

Comment: I am also having same issue. I am not not even providing any redirect url but it still redirecting to https://localhost/#. Some one help me to fix this. Thanks in advance.