# keycloak redirects to https://localhost instead of http://localhost

Tags: redirect, load-balancing, keycloak

Keycloak, behind of a load balancer, redirects to https://localhost instead of http://localhost after authentication.
Keycloak configuration is ok according to documents as below:

```
<http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http"  enable-http2="true" read-timeout="30000" proxy-address-forwarding="true" redirect-socket="proxy-https"/>
<socket-binding name="proxy-https" port="443"/>
```

The same problem as [Keycloak redirect URI gives https://localhost instead of http://localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57758394/keycloak-redirect-uri-gives-https-localhost-instead-of-http-localhost/66900650#66900650) but there is no answer.

Thanks,